# Finding $\|f\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given $f: \ell^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(a_1,a_2,...)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n-1}} a_n$$ Is $f$ a bounded linear functional? If yes, then find $\|f\|$.

---

It is definitely bounded. I seem to get the value of the norm of $f$ wrong. It is apparently $3/2\sqrt 2$.

Bounded: Let $x=(a_1,a_2,...)$. Then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n-1}} a_n \leq |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n-1}} a_n| =|\langle(\frac1{3^{n-1}}),(a_n) \rangle \leq \|(\frac1{3^{n-1}}) \|_2 \|x\|_2$$

The norm: $$\|f\|=\sup_{\|x\|_2 \leq 1}|f(x)| \leq \sup_{\|x\|_2 \leq 1}\|(\frac1{3^{n-1}}) \|_2 \|x\|_2 \leq \|(\frac1{3^{n-1}})\|_2$$

And, let $x=(\frac1{3^{n-1}})$, then $$ \|f\| \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n-1}} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} | \frac{1}{3^{n-1}}|^2=\|\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} \|_2^2 \geq \|\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} \|_2 $$ The last inequality holds because $\|\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} \|_2 \geq 1 $ so squaring it wont make it smaller.

So $\|f\|=\|\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} \|_2$. Is this now correct?

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: and $\|x\|^2 = \sum_n |a_n|^2$. to show $f$ is bounded,  say that if $\|x\|^2 \le 1$ then $|a_n| \le 1$ hence $|f(x)| \le \ldots$

Comment: Hint: with Cauchy Schwarz you know equality is achieved when $x$ is linearly dependent with $b_n:=(-1)^n/3^{n-1}$,  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{9^{n-1}}=9/8$, and $\sqrt{9/8}=3/2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: But i still don't understand what was wrong with what i did. It seems to work fine...

Comment: What went wrong was your assumption that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n = \|x\|_2^2$. Rather, $\|x\|_2^2 = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lvert a_n\rvert^2$.

Comment: Ohhhhhh i knew i made a silly error somewhere!!!!

Comment: @kobe I think I fixed it now. Please could you check and tell me.

Comment: In the first line of inequalities, the first series expression should be removed. In showing $\|f\| \ge \|3^{-n-1}\|_2$, choose $x = (\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n-1}})$, not $x = (\frac{1}{3^{n-1}})$; with your choice of $x$, the $(-1)^n$ part of the series does not go away.